# IE Text box error in search bar

Tags: internet-explorer, text, textbox

I have problem only in IE, when i start writing in text box i got ">" arrow at the end of the text box. [image]

In all others browser it doesn't show, anyone had similar problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the sample of your code, cause this way it is not possible to analyse where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is half of an `x` symbol that is added to input fields by recent versions of IE.

This `x` is a "clear field" button. IE has added it as a new feature in IE10.

The reason you're only seeing half of it is probably because your `Go` button is sittin on top of it, overlaying the edge of the field. This may or may not be intentional, but either way you can probably solve the issue either by moving the `Go` button, or adjusting the length of the field.

Which way you go with that will depend on whether you want the `x` to be visible or not. You could choose to hide it completely behind the `Go` button, or shorten the field size slightly so that the `x` is fully visible. Up to you.

*[edit]*
Alternatively you can use CSS to get rid if it you don't want the `x` to appear at all.

```
input::-ms-clear { display: none; }
```

This will remove it from all input fields. Or replace `input` with a classname or other selector if you only want to remove it from specific fields.

<sup>*(with thanks to @mikrimouse for reminding me of that CSS option)*</sup>

Hope that helps expain things.

Comment: class::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
This is the solution for the problem.

Comment: @mikrimouse - thanks, I'd forgotten about that. I've added it to the answer. (even if I didn't give you the best solution to start with, it seems that at least I led you down the right direction to the answer :))

Comment: I have another question for you but if you can give me skype or something to get live..

Comment: @mikrimouse - sorry, I don't think I have time for a live chat, but ask the question here, I'll see if I can answer it.

Comment: I will post the new question and post here the link, ok ?

Comment: @mikrimouse: sure, I will try to get to it see if I can help. May or may not be straight away (I'll be going offline in a bit).